# Validator Options in igniteui-angular for the igGrid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, infragistics, ignite-ui, iggrid

I have an [igniteui-angluar](http://igniteui.github.io/igniteui-angular/) `<ig-grid>` I am using and I want to validate the cells using validatiorOptions' checkValue event.

Here is my set up of the features section

HTML:

```
<features>
    <feature name="Updating"
        event-edit-row-ending="shiftBindHandler"
        event-row-adding="addRowHandler">
        <column-settings>
            <column-setting column-key="ShiftID">
                <editor-options type="text" max-length="4">
                    <validator-options event-check-value="shiftIDValidator">
                    </validator-options>
                </editor-options>
            </column-setting>
        </column-settings>
    </feature>
    ...
</features>
```

Here is the corresponding checkValue function

Controller:

```
$scope.shiftIDValidator = function (e, u) {
    console.log('Validator Called');

}
```

What is the proper way to use checkValue in the igniteui-angular format? There isn't much information out there on any of this stuff. [This paragraph](https://github.com/IgniteUI/igniteui-angular#handling-events) on event handling is about all I can find on the subject.

Thanks!

Julie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Infragistics got back to me on the issue and said it was a bug. The format above should now work for checkValue. http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/p/92125/455601.aspx#455601